# Kubuntu network connection information

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, network-manager, indicator

In Kubuntu 18.04, I could not find any connection information utility more than the up/down rates:

[image]

I need more data such as current IP address like found in the Gnome connection manager.

Comment: There is "Details for Public IP Address widget" but it's a widget you need to install by clicking on the ☰ icon on your panel > Get new widgets > and searching for *IP Address* in the search box. I haven't personally used this widget.

Comment: And if you're familiar with *conky*, https://askubuntu.com/questions/673590/how-can-i-get-ip-address-showing-from-using-conky/1108880 may help.

Comment: Following the AU link above, I modified my conky to show an IP address: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqZlc.png

Comment: Indeed, I need the LAN IP address instead of the public one

Comment: Then see https://askubuntu.com/a/673616/248158